# React Reducer is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have multiple properties already in mapStateToProps(state) but this particular bit is returning undefined - the disableselectors

```
return {
    token: state.token,
    url: state.url,
    disableselectors: state.disableselectors
}
```

so here is my reducer, I'm already returning a default state (same as my other reducers)

```
const initState = "ENABLED"; 

export default function disableSelectorReducer(state = initState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SET_DISABLEDSELECTORS':
            return action.disableselectors;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

when I try to access it on my component it returns undefined

```
doUpdate(){
let x = this.props.disableselectors;
}
```

Component where I set the state and action

```
 const disableselectors = this.state.disableselectors;
        disableselectors.disableSelectorProperty = "DISABLED";
        this.setState({disableselectors});
        this.props.setDisableSelectors(this.state.disableselectors.disableSelectorProperty);
```

root reducer

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    status,
    disableSelectors
})

export default rootReducer;
```

are there any issue for this? since my other props and reducers are working fine

Comment: export function setDisableSelectors(disableselectors){
    return {type: 'SET_DISABLEDSELECTORS', disableselectors}
}

Comment: We'll need a few more details. Before we know if your `mapStateToProps` is correct, we'll need to see the shape of your reducer (I'm assuming you have a `combineReducers` call somewhere). If you can, edit your question to add details so we get the nice code formatting.

Comment: yup, i have a combineReducers 
import disableSelectors from './disableSelectorReducer';
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    someReducer,
    disableSelectors
})

export default rootReducer;

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `combineReducers`, the property names that are passed in become the properties in the combined state. Because your `combineReducers` looks like this:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  status,
  disableSelectors
})
```

...your mapping of state to props

```
return {
  token: state.token,
  url: state.url,
  disableselectors: state.disableselectors
};
```

...is incorrect since the state you're looking for is under a `disableSelectors` property, not a `disableselectors` property (notice the capitalization you're using doesn't match the capitalization in your `combineReducers`). Either update your mapping function to access `disableSelectors` or update your `combineReducers` so the property is `disableselectors`.

(personally I'd recommend *always* using `camelCase` to avoid this sort of issue).

Comment: Thanks Jacob! Seems like I'm rushing my coding to get this done. I will take note of this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. I'd highly suggest installing Redux developer tools as well, since that lets you easily see your store's state which helps immensely in debugging problems like this.

Comment: cool. will do as well. fairly new with redux and react :) thanks